# How to call a two different JavaScript Hover?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, hover

I have a script (hover function) that pop-ups div. And it works when I called the "trigger" id. The problem is when I try to add another hover function that pop-ups another div, the second hover will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
      $('div#pop-up').show();
     }, function() {
      $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
      $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }); 


  });
</script>
```

Here is the code when I add a hover function to call another div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;  

    $('a#secondTrigger').hover(function(e) {
      $('div#secondPop-up').show();
     }, function() {
      $('div#secondPop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a#secondTrigger').mousemove(function(e) {
      $("div#secondPop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }); 

  });
</script>
```

When I call the #secondTrigger, it will not work. What do I need to change in my codes. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Is the `div` with id `#secondTrigger` present in the page and correctly defined. Is the `div` with id `secondPop-up` also present? A jsfiddle would be useful to help you troubleshoot your issue

Comment: I don't see any reason why they should interfere with each other, since they're bound to different elements and modify different DIVs. Does the second one work if you remove the first one?

Comment: can you please also post your page markup? thanks

Comment: @flochtililoch : Yes. The div with id #secondPop-up is present in the page.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle       http://jsfiddle.net/r5B5W/2/

Comment: @Barmar The second one works if I remove the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('mousemove','a#secondTrigger',function(e) {
  $("div#secondPop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem with sequence or syntax.
Try this code which I've checked and worked fine:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var moveLeft = 20;
        var moveDown = 10;

        $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
        $('div#pop-up').show();
     }, function() {
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
      $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    }); 

    $('div#pop-up').hide();
    $('div#secondPop-up').hide();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var moveLeft = 20;
        var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#secondTrigger').hover(function (e) {

        $('div#secondPop-up').show();
    }, function () {
        $('div#secondPop-up').hide();
    });

    $('a#secondTrigger').mousemove(function (e) {
        $("div#secondPop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });

});
</script>
<a id="trigger">trigger</a>
<div id="pop-up">pop-up</div>
<a id="secondTrigger">trigger</a>
<div id="secondPop-up">secondPop-up</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle on it? It didn't work  with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just give second  tag id ="secondTrigger".This is the Problem here......

```
<a href='#' id='secondTrigger'>Second Trigger </a>
```

Comment: In your HTML code ,Please see the second <a> tag's id.Please change it to secondTrigger.Then only it will call the second hover...